# Cassandra vs logging activity

Tags: logging, cassandra, kundera

I'm using Cassandra with Kundera. My question is easy... Is any way to log all queries / request to Cassandra ? I'd like to know what exactly happens on server site :)

Regards

Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable DEBUG logging for org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraServer

Comment: That doesn't print the CQL, at least in Cassandra 2

Comment: Where I need to add this line? In /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml?

Answer (score 1):

Enable DEBUG logging for org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message:

log4j.logger.org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message=DEBUG

This logs only PreparedStatements!!

for example:

DEBUG [Native-Transport-Requests:167] 2015-06-01 15:56:15,186 Message.java (line 302) Received: PREPARE INSERT INTO dba_test.cust_view (leid, vid, geoarea, ver) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);, v=2
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests:167] 2015-06-01 15:56:15,187 QueryProcessor.java (line 283) Stored prepared statement 61956319a6d7c84c25414c96edf6e38c with 4 bind markers
DEBUG [Native-Transport-Requests:167] 2015-06-01 15:56:15,187 Tracing.java (line 159) request complete
DEBUG [Native-Transport-Requests:167] 2015-06-01 15:56:15,187 Message.java (line 309) Responding: RESULT PREPARED 61956319a6d7c84c25414c96edf6e38c [leid(dba_test, cust_view), org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type][vid(dba_test, cust_view), org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type][geoarea(dba_test, cust_view), org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type][ver(dba_test, cust_view), org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType] (resultMetadata=[0 columns]), v=2